# How to read property from Class<T> instance in Java?

Tags: java, oop, kotlin, generics, java-8

I have a method `methodA()` that takes as a parameter an instance of a class `Class<T> inClass`.

Any of the given `inClass` instances passed in `methodA()` will have a property called `user:String`.

So I want to read that property inside `methodA()`. But I get `Cannot resolve method 'getUser' in 'T'`

Is it possible to somehow read the property from the generic class?

Alternatively, could I pass the name of the class I want as a String in `methodA()` and the convert that to "ClassName".class somehow?

```
private <T> Function<PredicateSpec, Route.AsyncBuilder> walletRoute(String server, String path, String method, Class<T> inClass) {
    return r -> r.path(path)
                 .and().method(method)
                 .and().readBody(inClass, requestBody ->
                    walletDiscoveryService(requestBody.getUser()).equals(server))
                 .uri("http://" + server);
}
```

I call the method like below:

```
walletRoute("localhost:3000", "/api/account/**", "POST", BankAccount.class)
```

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: How about Class<T extends U>, in which class U is abstract and has getUser declared?

Comment: No, unless you gave the specific instance of `T` also passed. Objects of types `Class<T>` do not refer to any particular instances of `T` by themselves.

Comment: @Fureeish, could you please show me how? When I call the method I do pass as parameter for Account.class, or BankAccount.class that both have the property I want to read

Comment: are you sure you wanna pass Class<T> instead of T ?

Comment: But you don't pass any `Account` or any `BankAccount`. Which object's properties would be reached from just an object of a type `Class<Account>`?

Comment: @Fureeish, could you please post an example? I cant grasp exactly the full extent of your advice.

Comment: @Fureeish, when I call the method I do pass the Account.class, or BankAccount.class - I have updated the post to show that

Comment: Account.class is not an object of a type Account. I do not know what `r` is in your code, but I will try to post an answer with example.

Comment: @Fureeish. Thank you. 'r' comes from builder.routes().route("string", r -> r. ...)

Comment: Why is this tagged [kotlin] if it's asking only about Java?

Answer (score 3):

> How to read property from Class instance in Java?

By itself? An object property? You **can't**.

---

Think of an object. A simple Java object. It holds all of its members and maybe some additional, inherited stuff. Let's say we have this simple class:

```
class Foo {
    String name;
}
```

after creating an object of a type `Foo`, we can access its internals like so:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.name = "Groot";
System.out.println(f.name);
```

nice and simple.

---

Now let's introduce some `Class<T>` magic:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.name = "Groot";
System.out.println(f.name);

Class<Foo> fClass = Foo.class;
```

Great, we have a `Class` instance. What can we do with it?

Before we answer that question, do notice that the creation of `fClass` *was agnostic (unaware, did not require to know) of the instance `f`*.

What does it mean? It means that it's in no way bound to `f`. It's bound to the `class` of `f`, but it has no knowledge of `f` itself. You cannot retrieve `name` from `fClass`, because which `name` would then be retrieved?

To fully understand this problem, consider the following code:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
f1.name = "Groot";
Foo f2 = new Foo();
f2.name = "Rocket";

Class<Foo> fClass = Foo.class;
//fClass.name ???
```

**If** `fClass` could refer to a `name` from some object of a type `Foo`, to which `name` would it refer? `f1`'s or `f2`'s? You can't know.

---

That's why `Class<T>` does something different. It enables you to get a generic representation of a field (for example, the `Foo`'s `name`), but it *won't yield* a concrete value (reference) unless *you specify the object on which that field has to reflect* (this is called *reflection*). Have a look:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
f1.name = "Groot";
Foo f2 = new Foo();
f2.name = "Rocket";

Class<Foo> fClass = Foo.class;

try {
    Field nameField = fClass.getDeclaredField("name");
    System.out.println(nameField.get(f2));

} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is a full snippet. Take some time to digest it.

Magic happens when you try to access a `name` *field*. Notice the `Field` type. It's an object which represents access to a field called `"name"`, in this example. But beware - we could've misspelled the field's name and that's why we have to `catch` errors like `NoSuchFieldException`.

Then we want to acces that field, but which object's `name` we want to access? Well, we have to specify that **using that concrete object**. We **need** `f1` or `f2`, otherwise we cannot know which (among possibly many) `name`s should be accessed.

By executing `nameField.get(f2)`, we say that we want to access `nameField`'s associated field (the `name` field from `Foo`) from object `f2`. But beware - that field could be inaccessible (for example it could be `private`) and that's why we have to `catch` errors like `IllegalAccessException`.

---

To be honest, you can access even `private` fields by doing a little more magic, but that's a little bit outside of the scope of the question. So, to summarise, you need an actual object of a type `T` to access its fields. `Class<T>` will enable you to do a little bit of *meta-magic*, but to have something concrete, you need concrete objects.

Of course, if you don't have a concrete object, but just a `Class<T>`, you can create a `T` from it using `fClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`.

EDIT: of course, your API may do some of its own magic with `Class<T>`. I am not faimilar with the API you are using (`PredicateSpec` and `Route.AsyncBuilder`), so I can't speak for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it using just a `Class<T>` argument, unless you’re willing to use messy and fragile reflection.

However, you can add an argument that represents the user property’s get-method:

```
private <T> Function<PredicateSpec, Route.AsyncBuilder> walletRoute(
        String server,
        String path,
        String method,
        Class<T> inClass,
        Function<T, String> getUserMethod) {

    return r -> r.path(path)
                 .and().method(method)
                 .and().readBody(inClass, requestBody ->
                     walletDiscoveryService(
                         getUserMethod.apply(requestBody)).equals(server))
                 .uri("http://" + server);
}
```

Calling the method would look something like this:

```
walletRoute("localhost:3000", "/api/account/**", "POST",
    BankAccount.class, BankAccount::getUser);
```